# wordpress wp_signon hang when i call this function but i already use same code and function on other site

Tags: php, wordpress

```
function new_login() {
    echo $username = $_POST['log'];
    echo $password = $_POST['pwd'];
    $remember = "false";
    $login_data = array();
    $login_data['user_login'] = $username;
    $login_data['user_password'] = $password;
    $login_data['remember'] = true;
    $user_verify = wp_signon( $login_data, true );

    if ( is_wp_error($user_verify) ) {
        echo "<span class='error' style='font-size:18px;'>Invalid username or password. Please try again!</span>";
    } else { wp_redirect( home_url() ); }
}}
```

I call this hook `add_action('wp_authenticate', 'new_login');`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `wp_authenticate` hook is called by the `wp_signon()` function. Inside your callback, you call `wp_signon()`, triggering the hook again... an infinite loop.

Comment: actualy wp_signon hook only work before the header so we need to use the admin_init hook for this...
but i want to chack the user from another api if exist in db then login using wp_sign other wise register user and then login so plz tell me how is this possible

Comment: I think I answered the question above. You said: "Please tell me what the problem is." Now, if your question is actually about logging in users from outside WordPress core, I think it's a good idea to a) research the topic and b) after trying it on your own, maybe write another question.